# React Redirection Doesn't Work on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, github-pages

In my main.js file, I have written the following code:

```
const Contact = styled(NavLink)`
color: ${props => props.theme.text};
position: absolute;
top: 2rem; 
right: calc(1rem + 2vw);
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 1;
`
```

```
<Contact target="_blank" to={{pathname: "mailto:email@gmail.com"}}>
            <motion.h2
            whileHover={{scale:1.1}}
            whileTap={{scale:0.9}}
            >
```

and it works alright on localhost. However, after I deployed the website on Github Pages, by clicking on the button, I get redirected to
https://username.github.io/webpage/#/mailto:email@gmail.com
Instead of
email@gmail.com

Comment: Try using DOM `a` component instead of `NavLink`

Comment: There's no reason to use a navlink here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NavLink from react-router meant to route in a SPA.
Just use the 'a' tag for this

```
<a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">Email</a>
```

or you should try

```
<Contact target="_blank" to='#' 
      onClick={() => window.location = 'mailto:email@gmail.com'}
>
...
```